# На что ругается codeception и как это исправить?

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

Установил новый проект yii2 - advanced, еще ничего толком не поменял в проекте, т.е. практически все настройки дефолтные.
При запуске codeception выдает следующее:

```
session_set_cookie_params(): Cannot change session cookie parameters when headers already sent
 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Session.php:388
 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Session.php:135
 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Session.php:635
 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php:653
 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php:252
 /app/common/models/LoginForm.php:59
 /app/common/tests/unit/models/LoginFormTest.php:63
 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:262
 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:145
 /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/codeception.php:40
```

Немогу разобраться, что это значит и откуда берется ошибка? Может быть это как то связано с тем, что тесты у меня запускаются с вируталки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже давно не давала покоя данная проблема. При попытке запустить любой из тестов (конкретно для Yii2) встроенными средствами PHPStorm получаю сообщение:

***session_set_cookie_params(): Cannot change session cookie parameters when headers already sent***

Долго руки не доходили, но вчера опосля полночных танцев со вселенскими бубнами выяснил буквально следующее:

PHPStorm (jetBrains для Google-а) используя плагин Codeception Framework размещает файл:

***C:/Users/dev/AppData/Local/Temp/ide-codeception_before_24.php:405***

из которого методом printEvent выводит в консоль логи через Printer::write():

***vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Printer.php:99***

как пофиксить это красиво я не нашел, поэтому "вот наш ответ Чемберлену!": в tests/_bootstrap.php прописываем **ob_start()**:

```php
    <?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
    require_once __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';

    ob_start();
```

сброс буфера в консоль происходит автоматически по окончании тестов. Получаем следующее:

[image: Пример запуска тестов codeception run functional]

Answer (score 1):

Вроде все понятно, `не может изменить куки, потому что заголовок уже сформирован.`Это значит что вы сперва делаете например `echo 123;` а потом пытаетесь изменить куки, так нельзя, куки изменяется ТОЛЬКО когда поток вывода - чист. Т.е. сперва трогаем куки, потом трогаем вывод.

Comment: Так непонятка состоит в том, что код проекта я и не менял толком. Я в данный момент настраиваю окружение, а это чистый yii2 фреймворк.
Единственное что я сделал, так это поменял настройки БД и настроил ЧПУ.

Comment: @RomanAndreev факт фактом, может ваши тесты что-то выписывают, либо ошибка какая генерируется, сама проблема ясна, а вот с источником не поможем, вам уже смотреть надо.